# DNS Swarm agent not working on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, docker-swarm

1- I created a new containerservice in azure.

2 - The creation was done following the portal step by step.

3 - I have not changed any configuration of any service, VM, balancing, master and agent.

4 - I can connect with PuTTY normally.

5 - I can open a tunnel by redirecting port 80 to port 80.

Following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/container-service/container-service-docker-swarm), I can put the container to run::

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
ffe6a1c890e4        yeasy/simple-web    "/bin/sh -c 'pytho..."   31 minutes ago      Up 31 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   vibrant_morse
```

If I access localhost from my browser I can reach port 80 of the container and see the identical "Real Visit Results" page of the tutorial.

But in the `tutorial` it says that if I use load balancer's DNS I should see the result, that's my problem, I can not access the container through DNS, I only get `timeout`.

Reinforcing, I created a container service and did not change any configuration, just entered with PuTTY and put the container to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that [you don't set your DOCKER_HOST environment variable to the local port configured for the tunnel](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/container-service/container-service-connect#a-nameconnect-to-a-dcos-or-swarm-clusteraconectar-se-a-um-cluster-de-dcso-ou-swarm). When you ssh to your master VM, you need execute command below:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=:2375
```

Run the Docker commands that tunnel to the Docker Swarm cluster. For example:

```
docker info
```

If you don't set the environment variable on the tunnel, the docker contanier is created on master VM, so you could not get the Web with agent Public IP.

Also, you could not set environment variable, but you need to point to the host when you execute docker command. More information please refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/04/25/create-a-docker-swarm-cluster-using-azure-container-service/)